# android - Sleep() and then draw

Tags: java, android, sleep, thread-sleep

I want to sleep and then draw in onDraw:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (_rectPath) {
        canvas.drawPath(mRectPath, mFillPaint);
        // SLEEP HERE for 5 seconds
        canvas.drawPath(mRectPath, mNPaint);
    }
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
}
```

How would I implement sleeping for 5 sec?
Basically I want it to wait 5 sec and then draw the next path, mNPaint.

Thanks!

Comment: what are you drawing in? is it a view or drawing ?

Comment: It's an onDraw in a view.

Comment: create a handler and a Runnable outside of onDraw void and then start it inside onDraw void . inside of Runnable just call invalidate(); witch will call onDraw again

Comment: `onDraw` is called on a loop, you should not be blocking or threading anything inside it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this method. Initialize Handler out side the ondraw method

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
And inside onDraw method


    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //Draw the previous paths.
                    // Adjust the paths here and draw it
                    invalidate();
                }
            }, 5 * 1000);
```

Comment: just saying ... :) but you have to initialize that Runnable outside of onDraw method .