# Java delay in a loop Canvas

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

Lines are drawn in a Canvas loop. I've tried a lot of doing the loop step by step with intervals, but nothing works. The presentation of the lines drawn in the loop is displayed at once without pauses.

This is my code in a Java class LineView:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
  for (i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    paint.setColor(Color.argb(255, 10 * i, 255 - (10 * i), 255 - (5 * i)));
    canvas.drawLine(pointArrayStart[i].x, pointArrayStart[i].y, pointArrayEnd[i].x, pointArrayEnd[i].y, paint);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
//            ------------------------------ The next Tread doesn't work the way I want
    try{
      Thread.sleep(100);
    }catch(InterruptedException ex){
      //do nothing
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Does this help? [android - Sleep() and then draw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36654543/android-sleep-and-then-draw)

Comment: @Abra ... I tried this but it doesn't work. Can you add the use of the handler in my code? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try calling `Thread.sleep(100)` before you call `super.onDraw(canvas)`? If that doesn't work and you don't get a satisfactory answer here can you reach out to the [Android Discord](https://discord.com/invite/android)?

Also, please add examples of what you've tried that didn't work, and a basic reproduction would be super helpful! Lastly, your question isn't phrased too clearly, maybe you could improve it before asking in the Discord?

Comment: Welcome as a new contributor. Please add comments about improving questions as a comment to the original question. =)